# How to prepare message before Assertion?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2019, assertion

I'm new to the testing, just started with "CppUnitTest.h" (Visual Studio2019). Assert static functions are performing well, example:

```
static void Assert::IsTrue(
    bool condition,
    const wchar_t* message = NULL,
    const __LineInfo* pLineInfo = NULL)
```

but i found that when such a function finally find mistake - it breaks the program(in my case test) immediately, and does only one thing - shows the message, which i should specify **before** such assert executes.

In testing, using loops, i can prepare full message with each iteration, but it eventually takes 6-8 times longer to run full test. So sane intention here is to specify complex message for assert only once, just before it break.

It feels like there is should be the way, but i can't find it on my own in the internet.

**My Example:**
Whole test(btw, any idea why UnitTest1 in test window 3 times nested?):
[image]
P.S. on test window is last assert shows only 'iter' wchar, 'msg' was not used at all.
Main:

```
bool applicableAge(UINT age)
{
    if((age>=18 && age<= 50)|| age==1000111222) return true;
    else return false;
};
```

**UPDATE** for @churill

I thought it unnecessary to paste my simple test of level "Hello World". Just imagine that you have function which takes simple uint, and my test want to test each possible input(above 4billlion), and now imagine that i put(intentionally) mistake in my target function, lets say it produces fault return if input is uint 1000111222, and now, in my test loop, i have to compose message at each iteration, which takes **at least** 3 actions: 1)initialize wchar_t with initial message, 2)_itow(i, num, 10); -convert current iteration digit to literal, 3)wcscat(msg, num); -merge necessary text parts in to single wchar_t, and only now i can put this to Assert as a parameter.

Now imagine i'm doing nested like 3x **for** loop, which requires like 3 different 'i' to be converted in to text, and then all this merge in to single msg. Then it becomes clear, that 80% of a test function is composing actual message, and 20% - is actual testing of functionality of production code.

And goal of this question of my, is to find out what kind of trick clever people with experience do).

I strongly believe, that should be something like "Assert::isAboutToBreak()" function(hypothetically), so programmer would be able to combine message only once, and it makes sense if you think about it, Assertion can be executed(fails) only once in program, and i fells a bit silly when i'm taking so much of program resources to 'preCombine' message **each** time.

Comment: 6 ot 8 times longer? What are you testing and how are you composing messages? Please show a [mre] or at least one of your test cases. We can't provide usefull answers if we can't see your code.

Comment: @churil It’s not at all difficult to see how the process of gathering information to make an assertion message maximally helpful could be time-consuming. And the answer is not “make it faster to compose messages”.

Comment: If you're using a loop, maybe you could reuse parts of the message `std::wstring message = L"Value should be x but is "; const messageSize = message.size(); for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) { auto const valueExpected = ExpectedValue(i); message += std::to_string(valueExpected); Assert::IsTrue(..., message.c_str()); message.erase(messageSize); }`; Alternatively you could perhaps write a template that generates the message only if required.

Comment: `Just imagine that you have function` Code speaks 1000 words. Please just post the code instead of literally explaining the code contents.

Comment: @fabian thats the point, i can't predict when it will be required.

Comment: Seeing your code, it looks like you have two sources of buffer overflow and thus undefined behavior. Arrays don't automagically grow. Both `_itow` and `wcscat` are writing out of bounds. Better use `std::wstring` or reserve enough memory in the buffers.

Comment: @churill no growing there, 'msg' in my case consistent(it's recreates every time), and 'iter' also don't grow, since _itow() replace contents of value i specify.

Comment: Yes, you recreate the string in each iteration and have a buffer overflow in each iteration. `wcscat` doesn't resize the buffer. It will simply assume the buffer is large enoug (it isn't) and append characters to the end of it. `wchar_t msg[] = "..."` creates an array that holds only that literal. There is no extra space reserved where you could append anything. Same for `_itow`. You pass an array of size 3. You can't store numbers `>99` (+termination `\0`) in array of 3 characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: Your code has undefined behavior. Arrays don't automagically grow, so `wcscat(msg, iter)` will always write out of bounds and `_itow(i, iter, 10)` for `i > 99`. I'd go for `std::wstring` and/or `std::wstringstream`.

---

But it's also apparent that the code you are testing takes almost no time in comparison to the time to compose the error message.

You could manually assert the condition (without `Assert::IsTrue` or `Assert::IsFalse`) and only if it fails compose an error message and publish it with `Assert::Fail`.

Rough example:

```
auto expected = calculateExpectedValue();
auto actual = functionYouWantToTest();

if(expected != actual) {
    std::wstring message = composeMessage();
    Assert::Fail(message.c_str());
}
```

Comment: Thank you @churill. As i said above, i'm feeling a bit silly while composing that message for each iteration)) Only when i read your answer now  i noticed that i could instead of direct assertions, simply make message and break the loops lol. As an excuse i'd say i had a quite hard week, so my brain get fuzzy and tired. Such a simple solution for so much text. Delete this post from the history of Humanity please.